# Conditionally disable React Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to conditionally disable the checkbox in react, based on the count. Passing the value through props whether it is checked and greater than the number. I am saving the name in the state to further process it to send to in the backend database.
Here is my react code.

```
class CheckboxComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                checkedItems: {}
            };
        }

         handleChange = (event, formKey) => {
            const {checkedItems} = this.state;
            const checkedValues = {...checkedItems};
            checkedValues[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;

            this.setState((prevState, currState) => {
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    checkedItems: checkedValues
                }
            });
            
        };

        render = () => { 
            const {checkedItems} = this.state;
            const checkedValues = {...checkedItems};
            const checkedCount = Object.values(checkedValues).length;
            const checked = Object.values(checkedValues);
            const disabled = checkedCount >= 3; 

       return (
         <div>
           {checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
                        <label className={`form__field__input__label`} key={item.key}>
                            <Input
                                type={`checkbox`} 
                                name={item.name}
                                checked={this.state.checkedItems[item.name] || false}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                formKey={'subjects'}
                                disabled={(!checked[index] && checked.length > 3)}
                            />
                            {item.name}
                        </label>
                    ))}
         </div>
       )
```

This is the Array that I am passing to render the values in the checkbox

```
const checkboxes = [
            {
                name: "Math and economics",
                key: "mathsandeconomics",
                label: "Math and economics"
            },
            {
                name: "Science",
                key: "Science",
                label: "Science"
            },
```

Comment: do you want to disable checkbox as soon it is mark as checked?

Comment: I want to disable checkboxes which are not checked and if they are more than 3 checked.

Comment: i see you storing checked status to state....so all checkboxes will be un-checked initially.

Comment: @tkamath99 Do you want a maximum of 3 checkboxes checked at any given time. If a user tries to uncheck than check, but not more than 3 should be checked. Have I understood the question correctly :)

Comment: Yes Imran. You got it correct

Comment: Let me see Bro :)

Comment: I have provided the complete solution for you with complete logs as well. This one was really really challenging, indeed. :) Any ways enjoy and do vote and accept the answer mate. Thank you :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Yes this 1 was really challenging. Thank you for the help bro :)

Comment: You are welcome mate. Life is about accepting challenges, I guess. hehe... NOW ENJOY Buddy. God bless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code snippet will work fine for you. And you can sent object to the backend having maximum of only 3  properties set to true. Get the full code from codesandbox link [https://codesandbox.io/s/emmeiwhite-0i8yh](http://Checkboxes%20Selection)

```html
import React from "react";

const checkboxes = [
  {
    name: "Math and economics",
    key: "mathsandeconomics",
    label: "Math and economics",
  },
  {
    name: "Science",
    key: "science",
    label: "Science",
  },
  {
    name: "history",
    key: "history",
    label: "history",
  },
  {
    name: "literature",
    key: "literature",
    label: "literature",
  },
];

class CheckboxComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: {},
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, formKey) => {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;
    const updatedCheckedItems = { ...this.state.checkedItems, [name]: checked };

    this.setState({
      checkedItems: updatedCheckedItems,
      count: Object.values(updatedCheckedItems).filter((value) => value).length,
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    const checkedValues = { ...this.state.checkedItems };
    const checkedCount = Object.values(checkedValues).filter((value) => value)
      .length;

    console.log(this.state.checkedItems);

    return (
      <div>
        {checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
          <label className={`form__field__input__label`} key={item.key}>
            <input
              type={`checkbox`}
              name={item.name}
              checked={this.state.checkedItems[item.name] || false}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              disabled={!checkedValues[item.name] && checkedCount > 2}
            />
            {item.name}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default CheckboxComponent;
```

Comment: This 1 was really great! Thank you so much !

Comment: Oh dear, it's my pleasure.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i disable a checkbox with a particular name from the array ?

Comment: Mate Have no energy left to think stuff . Would share a resource for you to learn and build on top of it. https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/react-form-part-2-cGKqZUQ  I have completed this full course many times in the past. Give it a try also :) Stay blessed. Would go for Dinner now:)

Comment: Hey... I am not able to find out how to disable checkbox if a checkbox with name is checked. Can you please help bro

Comment: In the same above problem or in general you want to know how to do this Mate !

Comment: You can consider the above example. If the name of the checkbox is Science and that is checked, i wanted to disable all checkboxes then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226144/discussion-between-tkamath99-and-imran-rafiq-rather).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `checked.length` counts all touched boxes, not checked only. If you uncheck an input, it still will be counted. Count only `true`, for example `Object.values(checkedValues).filter(value => value).length`.
2. Use names instead of indexes: `disabled={!checkedValues[item.name] && checkedCount > 3}`

You can see full solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-http-vlm04?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

```
event.target.getAttribute('name');
```

try this to get name attribute, pretty sure event.target.name is 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

I see one use case is not taken care of. checkedCount should count the number of true values only.

```
const checkedCount = Object.values(checkedValues).length; // existing
const checkedCount = Object.values(checkedValues).filter(item=>item==true).length //replace with this line
```

This would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code and as well as codesandbox link
**[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-gareth-yh5th?file=/src/check-box.js:0-1323)**

```
import React from "react";
export class CheckboxComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: {},
      checkedCount: 0
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, formKey) => {
    const { checkedItems } = this.state;
    const checkedValues = { ...checkedItems };
    checkedValues[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;

    this.setState((prevState, currState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        checkedItems: checkedValues,
        checkedCount: event.target.checked
          ? prevState.checkedCount + 1
          : prevState.checkedCount - 1
      };
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    const { checkboxes } = this.props;
    const { checkedCount } = this.state;
    const disabled = checkedCount >= 3;

    return (
      <div>
        <p></p>
        {checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
          <label className={`form__field__input__label`} key={item.key}>
            <input
              type={`checkbox`}
              name={item.name}
              checked={this.state.checkedItems[item.name] || false}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              disabled={!this.state.checkedItems[item.name] ? disabled : false}
            />
            {item.name}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```